# Reshape data to split column values into columns

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

```
df <- data.frame(animal = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat"),
                 hunger = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1,1))
```

I have a dataframe like the one above with two columns, one containing categories and the other containing binary data.

I am looking to reshape the dataframe to split the category ("animal") column up into two columns of its own with the values of "animal" column as column names and the values of the other column (hunger) as cell values, i.e.

Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(dog = c(0, 1, 0),
                 cat = c(1, 1, 1))
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What would you do if `df` was 7 rows and `dog` and `cat` weren't equal length? (Also, as an aside, I don't think this is a very good plan because the data structure is not very robust.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case of uneven length among different categories, we can use

```
list2DF(
  lapply(
    . <- unstack(df, hunger ~ animal),
    `length<-`,
    max(lengths(.))
  )
)
```

or

```
list2DF(
  lapply(
    . <- unstack(rev(df)),
    `length<-`,
    max(lengths(.))
  )
)
```

and we will obtain

```
  cat dog
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   1   0
4   0  NA
```

**Dummy data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  animal = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat", "cat"),
  hunger = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
)
```

---

We can also use `unstack`, e.g.,

```
> unstack(rev(df))
  cat dog
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   1   0
```

or

```
> unstack(df, hunger ~ animal)
  cat dog
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   1   0
```

Comment: I think 2nd version, without rev, should be the one at the top.

Comment: Great solution, how would you go about turning it into a dataframe if they are of uneven length as Ian suggests? I.e. df <- data.frame(animal = c("dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat"),
                 hunger = c(1, 1, 0, 1,1))

Comment: @Icewaffle what's the desired output in that case, i.e., uneven length?

Comment: Desired output would be even length with NA filling in bottom rows of smaller column

Answer (score 9):

Base R:

```
df$id <- ave(df$hunger, df$animal, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(df, idvar = "id", timevar = "animal", direction = "wide")[, -1]

  hunger.dog hunger.cat
1          0          1
2          1          1
4          0          1
```

Answer (score 9):

Using *split*:

```
data.frame(split(df$hunger, df$animal))
#   cat dog
# 1   1   0
# 2   1   1
# 3   1   0
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `pivot_wider` by first creating an id for each group to identify the duplicates and use the `names_from` and `values_from` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(animal) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = animal, values_from = hunger) %>%
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>     dog   cat
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     1
#> 2     1     1
#> 3     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly how I would have done it. I would have lovely implemented this one also `df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = animal, values_from = hunger, values_fill = 0)` but it gives error `Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't convert `fill` <double> to <list>.`

Comment: Hi @TarJae, I tried that also at first but unfortunately that doesn’t work.

Answer (score 7):

A tidy framework way

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = animal, values_from = hunger, values_fn = list) |> 
  unnest(cols = c("dog", "cat"))
```

Base R

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, tapply(df$hunger, df$animal, `+`))
```

Answer (score 7):

Throwing a `tidyverse/purrr` solution into the mix:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(animal = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat"),
                 hunger = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1,1))

df %>% 
  group_split(animal) %>% 
  map(~tibble(!!quo_name(unique(.x$animal)) := .x$hunger)) %>% 
  list_cbind()
  
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>     cat   dog
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0
#> 2     1     1
#> 3     1     0
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), rowid(animal) ~ animal)[, animal  := NULL][]
```

-output

```
    cat dog
1:   1   0
2:   1   1
3:   1   0
```